# Even I have enabled cookies, I still cannot login to microsoft

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, microsoft-account

I have enabled my cookies on IE, but when I login to my microsoft account, it always let me enable my cookie? Can anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: Login to Microsoft how? And enable what? You need to provide more information for someone to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reminding！I login to Microsoft by IE and Chrome.And I enabled cookies both of them.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to @U @Michael Todd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using another browser. This happens to a-lot of people that try to sign in or use something that evolves cookies and currently not working because it says that you don't have cookies enabled when you do. Clear all your cookie data, restart your browser and try again

Comment: Thanks very much. I now login successfully using Safari. But I sill don't know why was that? I have cleared all my cookie data and restarted.

Comment: This happens to everone, Not just only you! :). And your welcome @Fenny

Comment: Yes @Feeny this happens to everyone once in a while